# Complete recursively Set

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The set $\Sigma=\{ p_1\rightarrow p_2, p_2\rightarrow p_3, ... \}$

Is it complete? why?
Is it recursively axiomatizable? Why?
Is the consequences of this set recursive? Why?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints (assuming the $p_i$ are supposed to be atoms).

Is $\Sigma$ complete? In the sense that for every wff $\varphi$ it proves either $\varphi$ or $\neg\varphi$?? Well, does it prove e.g. any $p_j$ or $\neg p_j$???

Is it decidable what's in $\Sigma$? How does that relate to the question of whether $\Sigma$ is recursively axiomatizable??

Suppose a wff $\varphi$ only contains the atoms $p_0, p_1, \ldots p_n$; could you decide whether it follows from $\Sigma$? Can your answer be generalized to give a procedure for deciding of any $\varphi$ whether it follows from $\Sigma$?.